# WPF Not receiving routed events from user control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, routed-events

I have a `UserControl` which acts as a custom button, but since I changed my namespaces around  the routed click event no longer works. Essentially my namespaces look something like this:

`UI`
`UI.Controls`
`UI.Pages`

I have a `UI.Controls.CustomButton` which has a routed click event implemented something like:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
     "Click", 
     RoutingStrategy.Bubble, 
     typeof(RoutedEventHandler), 
     typeof(CustomButton));

public event RoutedEventHandler Click
{
     add { AddHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
     remove { RemoveHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
}

private void Border_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     Border_MouseEnter(sender, e);
     RaiseClickEvent();
}

private void RaiseClickEvent()
{
     RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent);
     RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
}
```

And I am trying to use it from within a `UI.Pages.SomePage` like so:

### XAML

```
<controls:CustomButton Text="New..." Click="NewButton_Click"/>
```

### C#

```
public void NewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //do something here
}
```

When I debug the application I see that `RaiseEvent` inside my `UI.Controls.CustomButton` is being hit, but the `NewButton_Click` inside my `UI.Pages.SomePage` is never called.

This was working when everything was in the same namespace... am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent); should be CustomButton.ClickEvent, no?

Comment: I am an idiot. I refactored as a part of changing the namespace and I guess that slipped through. Thank you so much. If you post that as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: Good stuff, glad you got it resolved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent);
```

should be:

```
RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(CustomButton.ClickEvent);
```